# WKRefreshBackgroundTask for CloudKit on watchOS?

Tags: watchkit, nsurlsession, cloudkit, wkrefreshbackgroundtask

So, on watchOS, I know you can schedule (and reschedule) a `WKRefreshBackgroundTask` to do work for you in the background. This is great for my app to make sure that data is current and up-to-date on watchOS - especially since it doesn't receive updates like iOS and macOS.

Except, my data uses CloudKit to store a user's data.

I want to use something like the `URLSession` scenario, where you schedule a `WKApplicationRefreshBackgroundTask` where you create a background `URLSession` task and hand it to the system. The system in turn hands you a `WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask` where you check if your data completed its `URLSession` (by checking if the downloaded data exists).

My question is, how do you do something like this with CloudKit?

I could just do the downloading of my user's data in the `WKApplicationRefreshBackgroundTask`, but I don't think I'm guaranteed it will finish in the time the system gives to my app. This is why (it seems) Apple recommends you split this into two Background Tasks:

1. `WKApplicationRefreshBackgroundTask` - to create the `URLSession` and hand it to the system.
2. `WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask` - to act upon the data downloaded from step 1.

I am not sure you can do this with CloudKit? Or, at least I can't seem to find something of the sort.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask` you have to access the iCloud database via URLSession. This is possible from an app but much more complicated.

- [iCloud web service documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitWebServicesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015240-CH41-SW1)
- [send a web request to iCloud from a swift app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/changing_access_controls_on_user_data)

Don't forget to get your API request token for your database on the iCloud dashboard if you want to try it out.

Comment: Do I request a token per user or per app?

Comment: You will have one API token per container but the in the App generated web token will be per user/session.